# Query has no result even parameter was copied for other query result

Tags: sql-server

I have database with collation Chinese_Taiwan_Stroke_BIN . On my first query, I was able to successfully get a result expected

```
Select project_name where project_id='LOC0001'
```

with result 'Location 凱滙 第'
But when I copy and paste the result on my next query

```
select project_id where project_name='Location 凱滙 第'
```

this yields to no result.
Upon checking, the issue is with this specific character '滙'
because when I use 'where project_name like 'Location 凱%', it will show result
but when I use 'where project_name like 'Location 凱滙%', it has no result

Comment: Have you tried `project_name = N'Location 凱滙 第'`

Answer (score 1):

The character '滙' is an Unicode character that why you need to insert prefix 'N'.Any time you pass Unicode data to SQL Server you must prefix the Unicode string with N

```
select project_id where project_name LIKE N'Location 凱滙%'
```